# PHP | How can i select the last index of array

Tags: php

i have a array and i want to select the last index
how can I select it
check the picture of problem: [https://xip.li/z3cePZ]
I am new at PHP I do not know what to do

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site or a replacement fo doing a bit of your own reseach from [The PHP manual](https://www.php.net/docs.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

by using end();

```
<?php
  $arr = array('Ram', 'Shita', 'Geeta');
  echo end($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

all you have to do is

echo $users[count($users) - 1];

Answer (score -1):

Use end() -function.

[PHP Manual - End function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)